# CSRF TOKEN on api serving application

Tags: node.js, api, csrf, csrf-protection

Currently, my architecture is like this:

1. API is served from api.domain.com.
2. Frontend applications are on frontend.domain.com.

My question is about CSRF protection and here are my approaches:

1. Get CSRF token on frontend application initialization from a call to some endpoint like `/getCSRF`.
2. Enable `CORS` on my `api.domain.com` and allow request only from `frontend.domain.com`

**Note:**

I found out that a major website is using something like my first approach to get the CSRF token, but I don't think it is a good approach.

Can anyone tell me which of my methods is better for CSRF protection??

Comment: how about calling the endpoint before responding and then responding with the CSRF?

Comment: I didn't get your point

Answer (score 0):

As the web app and the api are on different domains, authentication on the API cannot be cookie-based (well, it can, but that would mean a separate login to the api, which I don't think is the case).

So you are sending some kind of a token to the API somehow, presumably as a request header, or maybe in the request body, which is less common (and hopefully not in the url, which would still not be vulnerable to csrf, but it would definitely be a weakness and an anti-pattern for other reasons).

In csrf, an attacker gets your user to visit a different domain malicious.dom, and creates requests to api.yourdomain.dom. However, they have no way to provide a valid authentication token, so your api is not vulnerable to csrf. Had authentication been cookie-based, it would have been vulnerable to csrf, because cookies are sent automatically.

If the authentication on your api *is* cookie-based, then the simplest you can probably do is switching to a token-based authentication (sent in request headers).

**Edit**

Another option to protect against csrf in your case (auth token in cookie) is [double posting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie). Basically in the login response the web app sets a cookie with a sufficiently long, cryptographically random value. Upon each api request, the client reads the cookie and also adds it as a request header. All the api server has to do is compare whether the csrf cookie value and csrf header value are the same (no server state). Obviously, this csrf cookie cannot be httpOnly, but that's fine, if you have xss, any csrf protection is useless anyway. This works, because attacker on malicious.dom cannot read the users cookie value for yourdomain.dom, and he also can't set a new cookie for yourdomain.dom (as per the same origin policy).

Comment: Since its a web application I am passing token in the cookie with HTTP only so if my application is vulnerable to XSS my authentication is safe, but i am still vulnerable to CSRF

Comment: @iambatman Ah ok, so you're setting the auth cookie to the top domain. You are right in that having a httpOnly cookie prevents getting it via XSS, but is that worth it? (Theoretical question, only you can tell.) I edit my answer with another suggestion for your case.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, if I switched to token-based authentication, on every request  will attach the token in the request header for that I need to store it in a cookie (Httponly false) ,but if I am under XSS vulnerability my token is exposed??

Comment: @iambatman Yes. Your auth token then needs to be accessible to Javascript. The most secure you can do is store the auth token in an httpOnly cookie and use some stateless protection like double posting above against csrf. The most convenient though is probably token based auth, in which case csrf is not so much of a problem, but xss can take the auth cookie. Note that even if auth token is in an httpOnly cookie, xss is still very bad. So, your choice. :)

Comment: Just to clarify something, the csrf token for double posting (or some other protection) should be different from the auth token. Maybe that's obvious. So it's either auth token sent as a request header (not vulnerable to csrf, but xss can take the auth token), or auth token in httpOnly cookie + a different csrf token in a plain cookie, copied to request headers (xss can't access auth token, and protected against csrf, but in a modern web app, can be a little inconvenient if for example you want to access multiple apis with the token from the client).

Comment: From your comments I think this solution is much better  1)Token based authentication, token is stored in HTTP only cookie (Safe from xss).  2)The CSRF token is a cookie without httponly and attached in every request header  is it okay??

Comment: If you are ok with the auth token being in a cookie (you don't need to send it to another domain), then that is the best option, yes.

Comment: "you don't need to send it to another domain" what is it means??

Comment: @iambatman Suppose you have api1.domain1.com and api2.domain2.com, and authentication is on www.domain1.com. Then the cookie is only valid for domain1.com and you have no way to send the token to api2.domain2.com. If you don't want to do this, it's fine, but sometimes people need to. :)